# Declaration of inner struct in another struct results in error: invalid use of struct

Tags: c++, struct

This is my first question here. I started learning C++ this summer and I have a little problem with this part of the code:

```
struct Contact{
    char name[30];
    char surname[50];
    int age;
    struct Born{
        int day;
        int month;
        int year;
    };
    char mail[50];
};
```

Well, I think this part of the code is OK, but I have this function to enter information and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
Contact readContact(){
    Contact c;
    cout << "\t            NAME: ";
    cin.getline(c.name,30);
    cout << "\t         SURNAME: ";
    cin.getline(c.surname,50);
    cout << "\t             AGE: ";
    cin >> c.age;
    cout << "\t       BIRTHDATE:";
    cin >> c.Born.day >> c.Born.month >> c.Born.year;
    cout << "\t           EMAIL: ";
    cin.getline(c.mail,50);
    cin.ignore();
    return c;
}
```

I get following error message:

> invalid use of 'struct Contact::Born'|

Maybe it's a simple error, but I'm new at coding, and I can't see what I'm doing wrong. :(

Comment: `Born` is a type, not a member variable. It is basically like `c.int` which C++ doesn't understand. You probably meant to add `Born date;` to `Contact` and use `c.date` instead of `c.Born`.

Comment: You are trying to reference a type, as if it was an object. You would get the same error if you were doing `cin >> Contact.name;`. Hopefully, you can see why that is wrong.

Comment: and probably better to call the type `Date` and the member variable `born`, to avoid further confusion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, the symbol `Born` is a *type*, much like `Contact` is.

The simple solution is to declare the structure as an anonymous type for a variable:

```
struct Contact{
    char name[30];
    char surname[50];
    int age;
    struct /* No type name here */ {
        int day;
        int month;
        int year;
        } Born;  // Member variable name here
    char mail[50];
};
```

Comment: not sure, but I think I would not use an anonymous type for a public member. Why not give it a name ?

Comment: I would suggest changing `Born` to `born`, as it is more common to start class types' names with capital letter and class members' names with non-capital letter. This way it will be easier to understand.

Comment: @tobi303 Unless the sub-structure is supposed to be used by itself, it simply doesn't need any type-name.

Comment: @FilipHazubski That would be my advice as well, but then the OP would need to change all places where it was used. Keeping the name as it is is simply simpler. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can define the inner struct as anonymous type:

```
struct Contact
{
   char name[30];
   char surname[50];
   int  age;
   struct /* anonymous */
   {
      int day;
      int month;
      int year;
   } Born; /* member name */
   char mail[50];
};
```

This would mean that you have no explicit type for the inner struct (it's anonymous) so that you can not declare variables of that inner anonymous type in your other code.

To allow usage of the inner struct you can separate them:

```
struct Born_s
{
   int day;
   int month;
   int year;
};

struct Contact
{
   char   name[30];
   char   surname[50];
   int    age;
   Born_s Born;
   char   mail[50];
};
```

or give it a type name inside the structure (usage of the inner type: `Contact::Born_s`) like:

```
struct Contact
{
   char name[30];
   char surname[50];
   int  age;
   struct Born_s /* inner type name: Contact::Born_s */
   {
      int day;
      int month;
      int year;
   } Born; /* member name */
   char mail[50];
};
```

Comment: there was nothing wrong with it before, just that sometimes the difference between "need to do" and "can do" really matters. As OP is newbie imho it does matter...

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out `Born` as you have declared it, is a type not a member. But you can use it to declare a member like so:

```
struct Contact{
    char name[30];
    char surname[50];
    int age;
    struct Born{
        int day;
        int month;
        int year;
        };
    Born birthDate; //<- member declaration using Contact::Born as a type
    char mail[50];
};
```

This is useful since you can later use the type e.g. as a function parameter:

```
struct Contact {
    // ... member decleration
    void setBirthDate(Born newDate) {
        birthDate = newDate;
    }
};
```